# Run Postgres Command from Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, shell, postgis

I Work with Postgresql. I have Command

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4269  /tmp/t/Wards.shp aa | psql  postgis;
```

when i type su postgres and enter this command it works fine but from aa.sh file not

my aa.sh  is

```
su postgres; shp2pgsql -I -s 4269  /tmp/gismanager/Wards.shp aa | psql  postgis;
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
su posgres -c 'shp2pgsql… '
```

`su` command executes privileged shell, everything following it is executed *after* shell is terminated.